# Xcode 12: Distribute content page showing only 2 options

Tags: xcode, macos

I am building a CLI tool on macOS (without an info.plist, not sure if this is relevant). I am reading the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution) regarding notarizing before distribution, and it says this "Distribute content" UI should show 2 options: `Upload` and `Export`. I don't have those, I have `Built Products` and `Archive`.

Does anyone know what affects the method of distribution shown here?

Under signing and capabilities, I have selected "Developer ID Application".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please try this got to **Build Settings** -> **Deployment**. Now if the Skip Install is 'Yes' set to 'No'. Then try again to archive. Hope this helps.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because my CLI tool is not an app in Xcode's eyes. That's what you get for being a CLI tool... Effectively, this means distribution is harder, and you've got to use other tools (e.g. `xcodebuild` CLI, `pkgbuild`, `xcrun altool`)

### macOS app distribution methods:

[image]

### iOS app distribution methods:

[image]

Comment: Hello. I'm also facing this problem. It would be helpful if you explain how did you resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're building a CLI, you build the executables (`build products`). You can then run that executable.

Comment: I'm trying archiving an iOS app!

Comment: Then this question and answer is not related to you at all 

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing the same problem even after setting "Skip Install" to NO. Please verify the Info.plist xml file and make sure its well formed. Some code editors like VSCode format the XML to more readable format and apple Xcode is not friendly with other formatting styles(including tabs spaces creates problem!!).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are here and your project main target is a framework and you have another target that's supposed to build an app (like a sample app), make sure `skip_install` is set to `YES` on the main target and `NO` on the app target.

By simply setting the app target to `NO` it does not work if you have another main target that is not an app and it's used by your app.